# Can't run Google Coder on Mac

Tags: macos, node.js

I'm trying to run Google Coder on Mac following the following instructions: 
http://pi.gadgetoid.com/article/running-google-coder-on-your-existing-raspberry-pi-or-desktop-pc

Everything goes well until I have to launch the server. This is what I get:

```
node server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/sebasribas/Downloads/coder-master/coder-base/apps/auth/app'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at pingStatusServer (/Users/sebasribas/Downloads/coder-master/coder-base/server.js:187:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sebasribas/Downloads/coder-master/coder-base/server.js:278:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found this here: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/coder/issues/56

You'll need to install the relevant apps before it'll work.

```
cd ~/coder-dist/coder-apps/
```

Install the base apps that are common to all platforms:

```
./install_common.sh ../coder-base/
```

This copies the common platform apps to the coder-base working directory.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your error log you're missing a module. Did you run 'npm install' in the coder-base directory after downloading it?

Comment: Hi manxam, thanks for your answer. Yes, I did run npm install. I even tried with 'npm install -g' but it returned a lot of errors. I tried starting the process all over just to clean after any mess I may have made, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

A little tedious, I'm sure there's a more automated way, but...

Follow the robot instructions in coder-apps/install_app.sh

Basically, you copy the app directories from coder-apps/common into three places:

1. coder-base/apps
2. coder-base/static
3. coder-base/views

So that in each of these directories there is a folder per-app.

Then, copy the contents of those app's respective 'app', 'static', and 'views' folders into the root of the application directory.

For example- in coder-base/apps, for the "auth" app, I copied /app/app.js and /app/meta.json into the root level of the directory that I just created: coder-base/apps/auth.

You don't have to copy all the sample apps, but you definitely need at least the auth, editor, boilerplate, and coderlib.

I'd just copy them all to be safe!

Have fun hacking :)